# What are different in two way of loading a image by opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Can anybody tell me what is the different in two way of loading and proccesing image, for example.
The first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void main()
{
    Mat img = imread("maria.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout<<"cannot load the image" <<endl;
    }
    GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
    namedWindow("Maria", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Maria",img);
}
```

the second:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "maria.jpg", 1 ); 
    cvSmooth(img, img, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5);
    cvNamedWindow("maria", 1 );
    cvShowImage("maria", img );
}
```

I have some code in the second form and i want to wirte it in the first form, so how can i find a corresponding command ?
Can you help me to write this code on the first form (C++ API)

```
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){        
       IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
     cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(121,72,89), cvScalar(256,256,256), imgThresh); //RED
       return imgThresh;
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: The first one is c++, the other one is C.

Comment: `Mat img_mat(img_iplimage,true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example use the C++ API of OpenCV while the second one use the C API.
The online [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/) gives you the list of commands for C++/C/python API with a common search tool.

Answer (score 1):

The first format is for C++ API.

The second format is for C API.

Basically you remove cv prefix from C code and change IplImage pointers to cv::Mat references. But that is really very general way. For better understanding see the online docs.